# Spring boot simple cache

Tags: java, spring, caching, concurrency

I have such problem. My spring boot application authorizes users.
I receive JMS message with login and password hash, then make JDBC request to my Oracle database, and send the response via JMS.
But my application must process ~ 10 000 request per second, so I need to make the cache.
I wrote simple cache based on concurrent hashmap, where a key is login+passwordhash.
Is it enough? Or it can be a bottleneck in my app?

Comment: I don't think you can do better than `ConcurrentHashMap` out of the box

Comment: Well it depends on how much ram you have and how much of it your cache preoccupies. You can run tests and monitor it.

Comment: Potential problem is memory leaks. How to control session destory? how to introduce cache entry life time? What if your app must be scaled to work on 2 separate servers? I would say it's better to use external cache as the storage.